# modifying a jlabel

Tags: jlabel

I would like to modify a label.  I create it at the top:

```
JLabel curStatus;
```

and then in a method that starts up all of the gui...

```
curStatus = new JLabel("");
jfrm.add(curStatus);
```

then for the method that takes a string, and puts it as the status of the jlabel:

```
public void setCurStatus(String inCurStatus) {
    curStatus.setText("hi!"); <<< ERROR ON THIS LINE...
    curStatus.setVisible(true);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Where is the NullPointer? Java should tell you some line numbers...

Comment: i threw it in there late with the "<<<"  it does reach it, because i tried a system.out.print

Comment: That would suggest that setCurStatus() can't see curStatus. Is it in the same file? Is curStatus private or public or what? Also is this a compile time error? If so you might have to 'start up the gui' in the constructor. Shouldn't make a difference (haven't java'd in a while) but try this.curStatus.setText("hi!");

Comment: here is how i set it up: public class gui {

 JLabel curStatus;  it is a run time error.  and the "this" did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code snippet, it is clear that jLabel is null when you set the text. 
Obvious and only possible reason is : your GUI initialization code is not being executed before setting text. There cant be other reason at all.

You look again, and make sure that those initializations happen at the very first (call it in the top of constructor)

Answer (score 0):

either remove the `@param` from the method or use

```
curStatus.setText(inCurStatus); // instead of curStatus.setText("Hi");
```

and pass "Hi" as an argument when you call the method.